# Node Express API slow (with Mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When querying a Mongo collection with Robomongo on my mac I get all 3,430 results in just over 100ms:

```
db.getCollection('profiles').find({'Uploader':/iazi/})
```

When querying my Node / Express / Mongoose API running locally, I have to wait over 2 full seconds to get the exact same data.

Here is my code:

*server.js*

```
router.route('/profiles').get(profile.rawList);
```

*profile.js*

```
exports.rawList = function(req, res) {
  var domain = '@'+req.user.email.split('@').pop();
  Profile
    .find({'Uploader': new RegExp(domain, 'i')})
    .exec(function(err, data){
      res.send(data);
    })
}
```

Who is the culprit for these 1,900ms difference? Is it Mongoose? Is it node? Did I write something wrong?

Additional info: the following responds in just 8ms

```
exports.superSimple = function(req, res) {
  res.json({foo:bar})
}
```

Comment: are the queries the same? the first one is on owner the second is on uploader? you can explain the query http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/
and see what strategy mongo is taking

Comment: Thanks good spot. I tried again in Robomongo using Uploader, it's just as fast... I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspected Mongoose so did some digging. There's very little I could find on Mongoose performance but I did get [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/u2_DzDydcnA/discussion). It's pretty old but probably still valid as Mongoose is still doing a lot of magic for each object returned. Try doing it as a 'lean' query and you should get better performance as it just loads the data.

Comment: Thanks, it shaved a little over 50% off response time.